# Do I need Geoserver in this scenario for my website?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, geoserver, cesiumjs

I need to create website with CesiumJS and python. Also I'm using Flask. The goal is to add elevation on cesium globe and by drawing polygon to modify the area with python code. After processing the polygon data with Python, send the modified data back to the frontend to visualize the changes on the CesiumJS globe. How to do this and what extra libraries or databases I need to use? I already have the backend part ready. Need oly frontend part.

In the described scenario, do I necessarily need Geoserver?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.